# Nested data in attribute is not accessible

Tags: python

I have two classes (Student and Course). I'm trying to write a method for the Course class that will remove a given student from a course. However, there's a problem when I run 
`self.students.remove(student)` in the method. The error tells me that student is not in the students list. Printing the students list I don't actually see the values, but instead I see a reference to it:

```
print(self.students)
> [<data.Student object at 0x7fc9980334f0>, <data.Student object at 0x7fc998033580>, <data.Student object at 0x7fc9980428b0>, <data.Student object at 0x7fc998042a00>]
```

However, if I select a specific student at an index then I'm able to see the actual data.

```
print(self.students[0])
> 2020411:King,Maha
```

Why is this happening when trying to print the students attribute?

Code if needed:

```
from copy import deepcopy


class Student:

    def __init__(self, sid, last, first):
        self.sid = sid
        self.last = last
        self.first = first

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}:{},{}'.format(self.sid, self.last, self.first)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}:{},{}'.format(self.sid, self.last, self.first)

class Course:

    def __init__(self, crn, students):
        self.crn = crn
        self.students = deepcopy(students)

    def key(self):
        return self.crn

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.students) == 0

    def get_student(self, student_key):
        for student in self.students:
            if student.key() == student_key:
                return deepcopy(student)
        return None

    def __contains__(self, student):   
        for i in self.students:
            if student.key() == i.key():
                return True
                break
        return False

    def register(self, student):
        if student not in self:
            self.students.append(deepcopy(student))
        return

    def drop(self, student):              
        s = None
        if student in self:
            s = deepcopy(student)
            self.students.remove(student)
        return s

student1 = Student(2020411, 'King', 'Maha')
student2 = Student(2019399, 'Hess', 'Alvin')
student3 = Student(2020301, 'Chin', 'Yu')
student4 = Student(2019111, 'Hay', 'Ria')
student_list = [student1, student2, student3]
course1 = Course('CP104', student_list)
removed_student = course1.drop(student2)
```

Comment: What implementation are you using? When I try to print out a student object it gives `<__main__.Student object at 0x110ffe320>`

Comment: Additionally, `deepcopy` is not defined and your indentation for `drop()` is wrong.

Comment: So, I figure out how to get it to print. I had to change the __repr__ method, but I still can't get it to use the remove method.

The code I provided wasn't all of it. I just took out some snippets. I will edit with the full code so you can see.

Comment: @EricJin, I've updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with `deepcopy()` is that it creates an entirely new object that has the same attributes as the original one, yet they are not equal. For `list.remove()`, this compares the reference to check if the actual object exists. In your case, you are trying to remove an object that is not in the list.

Instead of removing it, if you want to return the student, use `list.pop()`.

```
def drop(self, student):
    for i, s in enumerate(self.students):
        if s.sid == student.sid :          
            return self.students.pop(i)
```

As a side note, it will be easier to do operations if `Course.students` is a dictionary such that:

```
self.students = {
    `sid1`: student1,
    `sid2`: student2,
    # etc
}
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively, implement `__eq__()` in `Student` so that `list.remove()` will work.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.sid == other.sid and self.first == other.first and self.last == other.last
```

Comment: Even if I remove the `deepcopy()` code I still get the same error:
`ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Comment: @exitthehouse Please re-read my answer. Don't use `remove()`. Use `pop()`.

Comment: Hi @drum, your last edit is exactly what I was missing. I didn't read the part in the textbook about shallow vs deep equality tests. Thank you very much!